# how to replace text which has ' using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

It' s easy to find and replace text in sed using

```
sed 's/text/replace_text/g'
```

But how to use this if we have `'` in `text` or `replace_text`? I want to replace `{` by `'{` for an `awk` script.

I tried different ways:

- `sed 's/{/'{/g' 22 > 23`

  results in `Unmatched '`.
- `sed 's/{/"'"{/g' 22 > 23`

  result in `Unmatched "`.

Can anyone tell how to do it?

Comment: Hi, please add some expected input and output to clarify the problem

Comment: hi Luciano,  I want to replace  {   in a file with '{ ..  this is for awk '{print}' ..